# Sizing down the value of 'g' for projectile motion

Tags: c++

For my school project, my team is doing a paper toss game. You get the input for angle and velocity manually from the user. For calculating the X & Y co-ordinates of the projectile I use the formula

```
y= x * tan(a) - (g * X * X/2 * U * cos(a))
```

When is run this , after a certain point of time i start getting absurd values, such as -500 or -1000 for Y. Sometimes it reaches -60000. I suspect that this is because of 'g'. Please help me out with this problem.

I forgot to say that i am running a loop , for x=0 to some value (co-ordinate which corresponds to range , specifically). Also we are supposed to code using MD-DOS IDE'S(like turbo c++; our textbooks are old) and i code using Turbo c++.

I have tried setting different values for 'g' like 0.01 and 1, but nothing seems to work.

```
#include <iostream.h>

#include <conio.h>

#include <math.h>

{clrscr();                                                                


  void projectile(int u , int a)  //function which calculates values of X&Y 

  {int vcos=cos(a),vtan=tan(a),x,y,int g=10;

    for(x=0;x<200;x++)
     {  int p=((g*x*x)/(2*u*vcos*vcos));

        y=(x*vtan)-p;

        cout<<x<<","<<y;  //cout statement to check the co-ordinates.
    }

  }
```

As values of X increase, I get really crazy outputs for Y like -32500 or -17000. I really suspect this due to the value of 'g' being used. Else it is a problem in calculating the angle value for each and every stage in the projectile. If anything else, please point out. Also please answer with functions or header files that are used in MD-DOS IDE'S (turbo c++ to be specific)

Comment: `vcos` and `vtan` aren't initialized.

Comment: I haven't checked that the calculation is completely correct (assuming `vcos` and `vtan` come from somewhere), I don't see what is wrong? There is no check for the "ground", so the projectile just keeps falling lower and lower at higher and higher speeds.

Comment: Have you tried printing all your variables each time round the loop. Then you should be able to see where the crazy values come from.

Comment: Your description sounds like the code gives the right answer and negatives represent the height after the projectile would have hit the ground, such as sending a projectile up and over the edge of a cliff.

Comment: int p=((g*x*x)/(2*u*vcos*vcos)); from where you get the u ? is not declered in this scope

Comment: Why are `vtan`, `vcos` and `p` `int`s? Seems like they should be a `double`s.

Comment: @AurelBílý ok i don't know how to do that. Can you please explain? Thank you

Comment: @Forgottenassassin I'm not talking about `x` and `y`, I'm talking about `p`, `vtan`, `vcos` etc.

Comment: @donjuedo the problem is that the projectile starts from the ground and not from a cliff as you say. Moreover i don't think we can have negative values of Y for co-ordinates. This is because pixels are used to measure co-ordinates in computers,right?

Comment: @Forgottenassassin You seem to be mixing up mathematics with pixels. Mathematically you can have negative numbers, it's up to you to write your program to deal with that possibility, not to pretend it can't happen.

Comment: @john then please explain me how to get around this problem? I can't get any idea/solution for this problem for more than a week.

Comment: @Forgottenassassin 1) Print out the values of all your variables as you go round the loop, this will let you **understand** what is going on, instead of just guessing. 2) Change the vtan, vcos, and p variables (at least) to be `double` instead of `int`. See what difference that makes. When you think about a variable, think about what it **represents** and choose the type appropiately. For instance if a variable represents something you can count, then `int` is appropriate, but if a variable represents something you can measure (like an angle or a distance) then a `double` is correct.

Comment: You can tell from the formula that `y` will eventually become negative as `x` grows. It’s only a problem because you imagined that “pixels” would automatically stop a number from becoming negative.

Answer (score 0):

The main error seems to be using `int` variables for floating point quantities.

```
int vcos=cos(a),vtan=tan(a);

int  p = ...;
```

In the calculation these are clearly continuously varying quantities which should be represented in a C++ program by a `double`.

```
double vcos=cos(a),vtan=tan(a);
double g = 0.01;
double p = ...;
```

etc.